# Проверка на наличие данных в Firebase и триггер исходя из результата проверки

Tags: java, android, firebase

Заранее благодарю, что нашли время и решили помочь, ценю время каждого. И так проблема.

По схеме, юзер делает авторизацию, в поле юзера 10 полей, и система проверяет, все ли поля он заполнил, если не заполнил, по умолчанию стоит `default`. Если система видит хоть одно наличие значения `default`, она должна выбросить диалоговое окно с предложением заполнить поля.

Проблема заключается в том, что система не реагирует. Оно либо выбрасывает окно, либо вообще не выбрасывает. То есть, у юзера есть поля `default`, окно выбрасывается, потом юзер изменил все поля и `default` больше нет, но окно все равно продолжает выбрасываться. Тут явно проблема в реализации логики, но понять не могу где и как это сделать.

Вот метод где идет проверка в БД

```
@Override
public boolean checkingForFirstNeededInformationOfUser() {
    mUserDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase
            .getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("Users")
            .child(getUid());

    mUserDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            needInfo = dataSnapshot.child("drink_status").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("ethnicity").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("faith").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("hobby").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("how_tall").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("languages").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("number_of_kids").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("relationship_status").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("smoking_status").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("want_children_or_not").getValue().toString().equals("default");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

    return needInfo;
}
```

Вот проверка на то, выбрасывать окно или нет

```
public void userNeedToAddInfo(){
    if (iMainInteractor.checkForUserInfo()){
        getViewState().checkingForUserInformation();
    } else {
    }
}
```

Надеюсь корректно изложил суть и инфы хватит, чтобы сложилась общая картина.

Comment: A = true, 
B = false 
A||B = true....

A&B = false
может не тот оператор применяете?

Comment: @EvgenOrlovsky не совсем понял. Я на верху показал то, как у меня написано.